# How to click on the element with ID "langSelect-EN" using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this so far

```
First_prompt = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#promptAnchor #prompt #promptContent")
```

HTML:

[image: The HTML CODE]

For whatever reason I can't add "#promptContentChangeLanguage" into First Prompt it gives me an error saying it can't find the value. I don't know what to do here. I have also tried getting the ID directly "langSelect-EN" but the same error occurs. When I just run the code I have everything is fine, but I can't access what I'm trying to.
An image is attached to show you what I'm trying to get to.
Any help would be greatly apricated. Thank you.

Link: https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

I'm expecting to get the element "langSelect-EN" and click on it with selenium.

Comment: If you add a URL, it'll be easier to help you debug this.

Comment: https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Answer (score 0):

I used the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Recorder to generate a script for that:

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python` or `pytest`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class RecorderTest(BaseCase):
    def test_recording(self):
        self.open("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")
        self.click("a#changeLanguage")
        self.click("div#langSelect-EN")
```

It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **English** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cc_btn.cc_btn_accept_all"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.langSelectButton.title#langSelect-EN"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cc_btn cc_btn_accept_all']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='langSelectButton title' and @id='langSelect-EN']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: cookie-clicker]

Comment: so does that mean that the pop up for selecting your language, does not load in with the rest of the code html code? because i'm new to sellenium and am confused as to what the code does.

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you come again?